# Combine multiple folders into one

Tags: bash

I was trying to combine content( jpg files: IMG_6837.jpg IMG_6838.jpg IMG_6839.jpg IMG_6840.jpg) of following folders into one "July.2015", I tried many ways from former question posters ([In terminal, merging multiple folders into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715014/in-terminal-merging-multiple-folders-into-one)) but still does not work.
Hope you guys can help me out. 
Thanks so much!

July 1, 2015

July 17, 2015

July 19, 2015

Manchester - Robertson - Tolland Tpke, July 18, 2015

Mansfield - Connecticut, August 1, 2015

Mansfield - Connecticut, July 11, 2015

Mansfield, CT - Knollwood, July 15, 2015

Newport - Rhode Island, July 4, 2015

University of Connecticut - Mansfield, CT, August 4, 2015

University of Connecticut - Mansfield, CT, July 10, 2015

University of Connecticut - Mansfield, CT, July 13, 2015

Willimantic - Connecticut, July 23, 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all those folders are under a folder called UNMERGED, then do this:

```
$ for f in /UNMERGED/* ; do rsync -a ./$f/ ./MERGED/ ; done
```